# Creating a contract contrainer with Brownie

Tags: brownie

How can i replicate this functionality with brownie?

```
// Deploy Uniswap Factory and Router
        this.uniswapFactory = await (new ethers.ContractFactory(factoryJson.abi, factoryJson.bytecode, deployer)).deploy(
            ethers.constants.AddressZero // _feeToSetter
        );
```

I've looked at the docs and i don't see a way to create a new Contract Container object from abi and bytecode.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import the compiled contract name from brownie

```
from brownie import <ContractName>
    
contract = <ContractName>.deploy(*args)
```

If it is already deployed

```
from brownie import Contract

contract = Contract(*address*)
```

or

```
contract = <ContractName>.at(*address*)
```

or

```
contract = Contract.from_abi(
            contract_type._name, contract_address, contract_type.abi
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I maybe didn't express my question correctly; the contract i am after is not compiled in the build folder. What worked for me:

```
from brownie import project, accounts
from pathlib import Path
```

```
    UniFactory = project.load(Path.home() / ".brownie" / "packages" / "Uniswap/v2-core@1.0.1").UniswapV2Factory
    uni_factory = UniFactory.deploy(accounts[0].address, {"from": accounts[0]})
```